# submodule bare repo issue

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I m facing a weird problem with submodules in a bare repo. I illustrate what I did.

I have a repo which contains 4 modules. It looks like this- 
*Superepo (top level repo)- *I added following submodules to this repo*:
        mod_1,mod_2,mod_3 and mod_4 (*internal submodules*).
After that I created a bare repo from this Superepo and call it superepo.git

Now I use this bare repo to share stuff across different ppl.

I cloned the bare repo along with all the sub-modules in a directory called ~/clone. (git clone --recursive ~/Superepo.git clone). 
I modified something in one of the cloned submodules (mod_1 and mod_2). I committed these changes to respective submodules. I also committed changes to the superepo "clone". (~/clone)

Then I pushed the changes to the bare superepo using "git push ~/superepo" which went through.

Now someone else tried to clone the bare repo. However, he gets an error as follows-->
fatal: reference is not a tree xyz (xyz = sh1 of mod_1 commit)
Unable to checkout xyz in submodule path mod_1.

I am kind of clueless what I could have done wrong. Am I doing something wrong with either bare repo or supermodules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should push the changes that you did in the submodule to the submodule's original repo. As of now you made updates in the submodule and updated the enclosing repo to look at that update, but for a new clone, it will have no idea of that update because you haven't pushed it to the submodule repo which is what will be seen when you clone.

Comment: I m not getting your point. Suggest the step which I am doing wrong:   Step_1 : I committed the changes in my clone. (~/clone/mod_1  and ~/clone).                                     Step_2: Then I pushed the changes to the bare repo from this updates clone.                                                         Step_3: Then someone cloned this updated bare repo. So, accd to my understanding this bare repo chnages should be reflected in this new clone.      Or may be I m missing some very imp concept here about git.

Comment: You need two push steps: `(cd mod_1; git push ...)` and (back in super-repo with the submodules) `git push ...`.  That way the new commit-and-tree are in mod_1 on the remote, so that people who fetch from the remote can see them.  A push of the super-repo does not update the remote's mod_1, only the remote's super-repo.

Comment: @agent.smith - You committed to submodule and did other steps and pushed the main repo. You should also push to the submodule repo as that external submodule repo is what is seen when you clone.

Comment: @mnojlds,torek: I got the point. I think my idea of setting up a bare repo was wrong. Is it anyway possible to pull/push things from submodule into my super bare repo. I think I cant push changes from my submodule into my bare superepo.git. Is there any better way to set up the bare repo?

Comment: You're right, you can't push from submodule to super-repo.  Doesn't matter whether it's `--bare` or not, it's a matter of: supers know their subs, but subs know nothing (nor do they care) about their supers.  The super's knowledge is pretty short: "sub named X (at url)" and "sha1 ID", but that's all it takes to identify the sub.